# Can I use a quad breaker to install a whole-house surge protector?

Tags: surge-suppression

I would like to install a surge protector in my panel.  I am limited on space and it calls for two 30 amp breakers. Is it possible to use a quad breaker?  I included a photo of the breaker.

[image]

Comment: It depends on your panel if you can.  Pictures edited into your question of the panel and panel labels will help.

Comment: Depends on panel... Do you mean if the breaker is compatible with the panel?

Comment: That and also if the panel is label for use of  qual breakers.  Not all panels are the same or even label/allowed the same if the same make.  People with more knowledge will want to see the panel and the labels/instructions on it before they will give a proper answer.

Comment: Specifically what is needed is the panel type and number. We are looking for numbers like 3040 where the first number is the number of full sized breakers the second is the total breakers allowed so in the above 10 tandem slots are available a quad requires 2 tandem slots. You may find a number like 2448 all of the positions can handle 2 per slot if your home is newer less than 40 years old it is likely there will be some slots available for tandem but the listing info provides this information and we need to stay with breakers listed for your panel usually the same name and type of breaker

Answer (score 3):

Unnecessary work. Surge suppressors don't need to take breaker spaces.

First, you can install a *wire-on* surge suppressor and have it share a large breaker with another appliance.  The surge suppressor isn't really a *load* per se, so it doesn't have an ampacity.  If the UL-approved instructions on yours says "don't do that", then send it back - there are plenty which allow it, and with wire-on surges, brand doesn't matter since bus stabs aren't involved.

Second, since "correct breaker for the panel" is in your vocabulary, I'll infer you have a Siemens lineage panel.  Siemens [makes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0052MG5K0) a plug-on "surge protector that goes where breakers go" **with 2 actual breakers in it**. They took the quadplex form-factor, hollowed out the middle 2-pole breaker, and put a surge there.  Since it has 1 breaker per space, it is a regular breaker (QP) not a tandem/quad (QT), CTL is not a factor, and it fits any panel where Siemens breakers belong.

Comment: So to "share" a breaker are you referring to wiring a pig tail (circuit & Surge Protector) into the breaker?

Comment: Is their a wire-on surge suppressor you would recommend?

Comment: @Mak2290 product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. Products & stores change too frequently for it to be of lasting value.

Comment: @Mak2290 Yes, or attach both wires to the breaker if it is labeled for 2 wires.  Some are (Pushmatic, QO).  I'm an Eaton guy myself. Any UL listed surge from a Tier 1 service equipment vendor (Siemens, Square D, Eaton, GE) should be fine.